# Why are integral and differential operators commutative?

Tags: integration, derivatives, operator-theory, surface-integrals

For instance, let's assume a constant 3D surface over time $S$.
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\iint_S \mathbf B \cdot \mathbf{ds} 
\quad=\quad 
\iint_S\frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t}\cdot \mathbf{ds} 
$$

Why is that? Why can I commute $\frac{d}{dt}$ and $\iint_S$?

I would appreciate formal answers. If you can provide references too, I would like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it when the function $\boldsymbol B$, and the function $\dfrac{\partial \boldsymbol B}{\partial t}$ are continuous.

Why? [Here](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jyang06/stat411/handouts/InterchangeDiffandIntegral.pdf) is the answer.

Comment: But that‘s only true when the Surface is compact. For the general case you need [this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement)

Answer (score -6):

Here is a short answer. Integral are sums (Riemann sums) and derivatives are differences (to the limit). Sums and differences are commutative.

Comment: This is so wrong.